# MATLAB Delay an Input Signal

Tags: matlab, input, signals, signal-processing, timedelay

I have the following input signal:

```
u = @ (t) cos(5*t)*sin(2*t)
```

What is the best way to delay this signal for a certain amount of time,`k`, in seconds without using any prebuilt MATLAB functions?

Comment: Further to what Cris said, what does "without using any prebuilt MATLAB functions mean"? Are you allowed to use `cos` and `sin` which are built-in? How about subtraction? Please (re)read [ask] and [edit] your question to include a [mcve] if this is a programming issue

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes. I meant to write ```u = @ (t) cos(5*t)*sin(2*t)```

Comment: @Wolfie By specifying prebuilt I wanted to emphasize not using any pre written functions, but since the solution is simply shifting the function to the right by ```k```, there was really no need to specify this.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I would like to do this in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can substitute `t` with `(t - k)`.

I suppose the unit of `t` is in seconds [s]. If so just do something like:

```matlab
k = 5;
u = @ (t) cos(5*(t - k))sin(2*(t - k));
```

This moves the signal to the "right" by `k = 5` seconds, meaning it will be delayed.

I hope that was what you meant?

Comment: You added some MATLAB syntax to original code that was not valid MATLAB syntax, the combination is still not valid MATLAB syntax. This will not run in MATLAB. On the other hand, I don’t know what OP was attempting with their code either.

Comment: With the updated question, this answer could become `v = @(t)u(t-k)`.

Comment: @sab0 Yes. This is what I meant. The correct MATLAB syntax should be: ```k=5; u = @(t) cos(5*(t - k))*sin(2*(t - k))```